# Класс базы данных для android

Tags: java, android, база-данных, libgdx

Я новенький в Java и SQL, поэтому хочу спросить, как написать класс базы данных, используя библиотеку gdx-sqlite? Можно ли какие-нибудь ссылки на примеры? 
Мне нужно написать класс создающий базу данных, если она отсутсвует. Так же мне нужны методы для добавления и  чтения 1 строковой переменной и 1 числовой.

Comment: Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 3-е изд.  14 глава

Comment: Глянь тут, все разжовано и с примерами Начиная от урока 34. https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html